# How to add vertical grid line to my d3 chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, gridlines

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. I've followed some tutorials([Vertical grid](https://bl.ocks.org/wadefagen/raw/ce5d308d8080130de10f21254273e30c/)[Simple gridlines in d3js v4](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/11bd68cce12df5678b483e5c8bac30cd)) about making gridlines in 3DJS V4, and I've tried to combine their code with my own.

My chart looks like this:
[image]

However I would like to have some vertical grid lines in the svg, so the chart will be easier to read.

**My code:**

```
function makeChart(desktopData,mobileData,tabletData){
    console.log(desktopData);
    var WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 300,
        MARGINS = {
                top:20,
            right:20,
            bottom:20,
            left:50
        }
    var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
        WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 300,
        MARGINS = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 50
        },
        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left,WIDTH-MARGINS.right]).domain([00,23]),

        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([00,100]),

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)


        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .ticks(10)
            .tickPadding(20)
            .orient("left");

    vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d){
            return xScale(d.uur);
        })
        .y(function(d){
            return yScale(d.pageviews);
        });

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(desktopData))
        .attr('stroke','deepskyblue')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(mobileData))
        .attr('stroke','orange')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');

    vis.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', lineGen(tabletData))
        .attr('stroke','deeppink')
        .attr('stroke-width',2)
        .attr('fill','none');



// gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_gridlines() {
        return d3.svg.axis(yScale)
    }

    // add the Y gridlines
    vis.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_gridlines()
            .tickSize(-WIDTH)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

}
```

**My css:**

```
.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken in your CSS your `.grid path{stroke-width:0;}` should read `.grid path{stroke-width:0.5;}` the 0.5 can be which ever number you would like. A stroke width of 0 effectively removes the lines.